# Socket Error Python

Tags: python, sockets

I had the following code and I cannot observe the behaivour of server and receiver client because client sender pops error continiously. How can I handle this?

```
Error: An existing connection is forced to shut down by a remote computer
```

**Client Sender**

```
 import socket
 import sys
 serverName = 'localhost'
 serverPort = 12000
 while True:
     with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
         s.connect((serverName, serverPort))
         f = open("sentfile.txt")
         l = f.read(2097152)
         while(l):
             l_bytes = bytes(l, "utf-8")
             s.sendall(l_bytes)
```

**Server**

```
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('localhost', 12000))
    s.listen(1)
    print ("The server is ready")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by ', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(2097152)
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as p:
                 p.bind(('localhost', 1000))
                 conn2, addr2 = p.accept()
                 with conn2:
                    conn2.sendall(data)
```

**Client Receiver**

```
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('localhost', 1000))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        while True:
            f = open('receivedfile.txt', 'ba')
            data = connRev(2097152)
            f.write(data)
            f.close()
```

Comment: source and destination cannot be the same as the port number. `Server (tcp/udp) <==> Client (create_connection method)`

Answer (score 0):

first you have to import Socket module. Then use the function `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: I already did import Socket module and never seen such method getaddinfo() in any guide site. I do not know where to use that.

Comment: @MickyA. [The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo)